# defining precision in python(2.6) division

Tags: python, floating-point, string-formatting

from **future** import division
To perform a division in which I need some percision. However, it gives a long number, like:

```
1.876543820098765
```

I only need the the first two numbers after "." => 1.87
How can I do that?

Comment: what do you do with this number?

Comment: i am saving it to a file

Comment: And you're sure you do _not_ want a correctly rounded number?

Comment: and why don't you want correct rounding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"%0.2f" % yournumber
```

As you said you don't want a rounded number, you might want to try

```
def twoDigits(x):
    return int(100*x)/100.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The number are stored as binary floating point.  If you need to show just two digits, you can turn the float into a string and control the number of digits displayed using `printf` like syntax.

```
mystring = "%.2f" % (x/y)
```

This will limit the string to have only 2 digits after the decimal point.

if `x/y` = 1.876543820098765
`mystring` = "1.88"

Answer (score 1):

```
f = 1.876543820098765
print f
print round(f, 2)

>> 1.8765438201
>> 1.88
```